# neo4j and max open files

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I'm using neo4j 1.8M06 on ubuntu. When I start it, I get this warning:

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended.
```

what does it mean? If it is required, how can I adjust this setting?

I've seen [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/7-H8Or1PJg4) on the issue but still could not understand it.

Answer (score 15):

It means that you can open only '1024'(default) files for writing. But `NEO4J` recommends this value to be `40K`. This can be achieved with the fix as described below.

Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add these two lines:

```
root   soft    nofile  40000
root   hard    nofile  40000
```

The neo4j recommends "neo4j" in place of "root" here. That won't work.

You also need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` and add the following line to the end:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

And yes, finally you've to restart NEO4J.

```
sudo service neo4j-service restart
```

Reference: [NEO4J server setup](http://www.codiply.com/blog/standalone-neo4j-server-setup-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Don't forget to restart after that

Comment: The Neo4j documentation did not work for me, however this answer did.  Running Neo4j 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I put the "session required pam_limit.so" in /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive, presumably because I am running neo4j as a service and used "root" as described in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

For now(neo4j 3.1.1), neo4j has the official solution for this.

Most Neo4j configuration goes into neo4j.conf. Some package-specific options are set in /etc/default/neo4j.

Add this config to /etc/default/neo4j

```
NEO4J_ULIMIT_NOFILE=40000
```

then restart the neo4j service to get it work.

```
sudo service neo4j start
```

see

- https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/#debian-operation
- https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-set-max-open-files-for-debian-installs/

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 & Neo4j 3.1.1

Comment: This is by far the simplest config change. Confused as to why this isn't the default given the strong recommendation...

Comment: In neo4j `3.5.x` on Debian, the conf in `/etc/default/neo4j` are overrided by systemd. See `systemctl cat neo4j.service` to see where it's overrided