# Error starting neo4j 2.2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, neo4j

I've installed neo4j version 2.2.3 from the PPA (as per instructions here: http://debian.neo4j.org/) and made changes to system limits on open files (as per instructions here: [neo4j and max open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596177/neo4j-and-max-open-files) among other places).

Alas, it fails to start. I've turned on FINEST logging and get the following error in `/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log`

`2015-08-09 08:44:56.954+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474] Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:258)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:117)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:619)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.info(JettyAwareLogger.java:314)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.(AbstractLifeCycle.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.createQueuedThreadPool(Jetty9WebServer.java:191)
        at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:152)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:474)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:230)
        ... 2 more`

It appears something is missing?

Comment: Just tried this locally - works fine on my machine. I guess you have a wrong (or multiple) version of slf4j on your classpath. What's the output of ` grep slf4j /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log` ?

Comment: Aha. Success! There was another slf4j library lying around in a base Java path. I have no idea why it was there, because a dpkg -S didn't show it belonging to anything. I'll update with an answer to my own question. I'm new to actually posting here, so apologies for weird formatting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was another `slf4j` library lying around in `/usr/java/packages/lib/ext`. Found it thanks to @stefan-ambruster suggestion.

`2015-08-09 23:39:46.655+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474] Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
     [loader.1] file:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
     [classpath + loader.0] file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
     [loader.1] file:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
     [classpath + loader.0] file:/usr/share/neo4j/system/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
2015-08-09 23:41:20.075+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474] Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;`

It seems `slf4j` is extremely version sensitive, so beware of having a main system version that's not the same version as that wanted by neo4j.

I removed the old `slf4j` library from `/usr/java/packages/lib/ext` and neo4j is now starting as expected.

Huzzah!